# how to convert the stored procedure to Linq

Tags: sql, linq, stored-procedures

this is my Stored Procedure how to write in Linq
please help me

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE sample
      (@LID var char(20)=null   
      )
    As
      SET NO COUNT ON;
    begin

    declare @err1 int
    begin transaction


   BEGIN
      Select * from sample_table where  Aid is not null and Sid is not null and @LID IS NULL OR Lid = @LID 
      order by SrNo1, SrNo2, SrNo3
   END
```

Comment: What is your source for Linq? Do you use linq-to-sql or EF or do you have your own objects?

Comment: actually this is my stored procedure .how to write in linq query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need this:

```
var query = dbContext.DraftLOB
    .Where(u => u.AssemblyId.HasValue &&
                u.SessionId.HasValue &&
                @LOBID == null ? true : u.LOBId == @LOBID)
    .OrderBy(u => u.SrNo1)
    .ThenBy(u => u.SrNo2)
    .ThenBy(u => u.SrNo3)
    .ToList();
```